# DynamoDB transaction write more than 25 items

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

According to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html

There's a limit of 25 items in the same transaction.

I need to make a transaction for more than 25 items, so I ended up thinking about splitting the array of items in chunks of 25 items and send one transaction request for each chunk.

The problem I think I will have is that if some transaction request fails, dynamoDB will only rollback the items of that request and not the items in the other requests.

I don't know how to solve that problem, any help or ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: This is a common problem in batch job based architectures. I did a lot of work with spring batch in SQL to the same time but without knowing your use case I don't know if it's appropriate for your use case. It probably would support dynamodb writers too. Maybe read up on that.

Answer (score 1):

Since September 2022, [DynamoDB supports up to 100 actions per transaction](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/09/amazon-dynamodb-supports-100-actions-per-transaction/)

But

> I don't know how to solve that problem

You can't. If you need to write 101 items, you need to issue two Transactional Writes.

Comment: What's the best way to issue multiple transactional writes?